# Searchview how search again after fragment resume

Tags: java, android, searchview

I have a `SearchView` in the action bar, this search view filters a `ListView`.
After click on the `ListView` its starts a new `fragment`.

After closing the fragment the Focus is on the search view (with the search words) and the keyboard is shown, But the search is inactive. After click on enter search, an activity opens.
How can I Do that automatically?

Comment: Use addTextChangedListener on SearchView edittext.

Comment: There is no textchangelistener only onquerytextlistener an this i have already add